# Reading image metadata

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I'm using Delphi XE5 and have a VCL application, where i show different images made by camera in a TImage component. The camera saved additional information e.g. GPS-coordinates, creation date, and so on.

When i show the picture i also want to show serveral additional information.

I tried the CCR.Exif library but it seems it didn't work with Delphi XE5 within a VCL application because i get several compile errors.

How can i get the metainformation of the picture?

Comment: Careful with CRC library. I get some random AV when I use it. Some stuff is not free properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCR Exif does work on XE5 as Chris explains in this blog post: https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/ccr-exif-v1-5-3-android-app-in-google-play/

You presumably have an out of date version of the library. Get the latest version from the source control repo: https://github.com/esmondb/ccr-exif

Comment: where can i get the latest version of the exif-library that works with XE5 within a vcl-application?

Comment: I did a websearch which took me here: https://github.com/esmondb/ccr-exif  You do need to be prepared to do some hunting sometimes.....

Comment: @David I am using the latest version 1.5.1 of CCR.Exif with Delphi 2010 running on Windows 10 and I too am getting unexpected errors.  I looked at various other libraries and they all seem to have problems.